# error: package org.ros2.android.core does not exist

Tags: ros, ardent

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I buid ros2_android_examples, error(error: package org.ros2.android.core does not exist   ) ocurred.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286820/error:-package-org.ros2.android.core-does-not-exist/) by [Pedestrian1671022](https://answers.ros.org/users/34354/pedestrian1671022/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-03-27**:
Not sure if the ROS 2 for Android developer is watching, @esteve, but you'll probably want to provide more information, like what tutorial you're following and/or what exact commands you're running to get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks @william for tagging me, this is the first question on ROS answers about ros2-java, woohoo! :-)

@pedestrian1671022 Could you provide a little bit more of context? ros2-java uses ament, the ROS2 build system, so you can't use Gradle directly with the Android examples. Let me know if you need help with the instructions in https://github.com/esteve/ros2_java#sounds-great-how-can-i-try-this-out Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [esteve](https://answers.ros.org/users/4526/esteve/) with karma: 89 on 2018-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0